# `Start-Process PowerShell` with -ArgumentList of type command does not invoke command

Tags: powershell

I execute the following lines in powershell :

```
$argList = "-NoExit -NoProfile -Command {Write-Host 'hello world'}";
Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList $argList;
```

My desired output is to create a new powershell windows and output the `hello world`.

But what I get is opening a new powershell windows and writing the command itself like `Write-Host 'hello world'`. So the Write-Host actually is not executed in the new window. how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the quoting of the $argList string in which you insert the scriptblock as text.

Try any of these:

```
$argList = "-NoExit -NoProfile `"Write-Host 'hello world'`""                # works
$argList = "-NoExit -NoProfile -Command `"Write-Host 'hello world'`""       # works
$arglist = '-NoExit', '-NoProfile', '-Command', 'Write-Host "hello world"'  # works
$arglist = '-NoExit', '-NoProfile', '-Command', {Write-Host "hello world"}  # works
$argList = '-NoExit -NoProfile -Command', {Write-Host "hello world"}        # works
$argList = '-NoExit -NoProfile -Command', 'Write-Host "hello world"'        # works

Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList $argList
```

Comment: Another variant that works: `$argList = "-NoExit -NoProfile Write-Host 'hello world'"`

Comment: @zett42 Yes, probably half a dozen more. Personally I prefer using an array instead of a string, because it makes quoting less confusing.

Comment: Theo, using an array is _conceptually_ the best approach, but is, unfortunately, ill-advised due to a long-standing bug in `Start-Process` - see [GitHub issue #5576](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576), where introducing a new `-ArgumentArray` / `-arga` parameter is proposed to make arrays work robustly. /cc @zett42

Comment: @mklement0 Ah, I have never ran into that bug before (just luck I guess) and didn't know that. Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 6):

[Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65759036/45375) provides effective solutions; to add some **background information**:

It is **only from *inside* a PowerShell session**, in ***direct* invocation of `powershell.exe`**, the *Windows PowerShell* [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)<sup>[1]</sup>, that **you can use a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) *by itself***<sup>[2]</sup>; e.g.:

```
# Works, but only from inside a PowerShell session.'
# -Command may be omitted.
PS> powershell -NoProfile -Command { Write-Host 'hello world' }
hello world
```

By contrast, **calling the CLI via [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) invariably behaves like an invocation *from the outside***, where **everything following `-Command` is parsed as *strings***, and, after removing outer `"` quoting, the resulting tokens are joined with spaces and then interpreted as PowerShell source code, **as if you had submitted that code from inside PowerShell**.

Submitting a script block *by itself* inside a PowerShell session does *not* results in its *execution*; it simply outputs its *verbatim* content (except `{` and `}`), and that is what you saw:

```
# Submitting a script block *definition* without *calling it* prints
# its verbatim content as a string, it is the equivalent of calling .ToString()
# on it.
PS> { Write-Host 'hello world' }
Write-Host 'hello world'
```

Therefore, **you could have made your solution work simply by prepending `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) to the embedded script** block in order to ensure its *execution*:

```
# Note the `&` before the script block to ensure that it is *called*.
$argList = "-NoExit -NoProfile -Command & { Write-Host 'hello world' }"
Start-Process pwsh -ArgumentList $argList
```

---

<sup>[1] This applies analogously to `pwsh`, the *PowerShell (Core) 7* [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh).</sup>

<sup>[2] In this scenario, PowerShell translates the script block as well as any arguments into Base64-encoded strings behind the scenes,  and passes them via `-EncodedCommand` and `-EncodedArguments`, along with `-OutputFormat Xml`. The receiving PowerShell process decodes these strings, executes the command, and serializes the output objects as CLIXML, which the calling PowerShell session automatically deserializes, which ensures rich type support, albeit within the limits of serialization - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74228152/45375) for details.

It is the need for this behind-the-scenes translation / deserialization that implies that the technique can only work *from  PowerShell*.</sup>