# Open pwsh with command from cmd without exiting

Tags: powershell, ssh, cmd, powershell-core

I am trying to start a Powershell window that starts an ssh session with the following command:

`pwsh.exe -noexit -Command {ssh <username>@<host>}`

This works when executed from a pwsh.exe window itself:
[image]
but when executed from cmd, the run window (Win+R) or Task Scheduler (what I need it for), it just displays the command that should have been executed and starts pwsh:
[image]

That is, the command that doesn't work *outside* of PowerShell is:

```
pwsh.exe -noexit -Command {ssh username@host}
```

The commands have of course been tested with actual websites where, again, 1 works and 2 doesn't.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note:

- The **answer below applies to the CLIs of *both* PowerShell editions**,  ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md))
- `powershell -Command "& { ... }"` / `pwsh -Command "& { ... }"` is an **anti-pattern**, and therefore **to be avoided**:

  - **Use `"..."`, not `"& { ... }"`, i.e. specify all commands *directly***,<sup>[1]</sup> which avoids unnecessary syntactic ceremony and unnecessary processing (though the latter won't matter in practice).
  - This anti-pattern, which is unfortunately very common, presumably arose because older versions of the CLI documentation erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

---

**tl;dr**

- **From *inside* PowerShell**, use **`pwsh { ... }`** (`-Command` implied); in  your case:

  ```bash
  pwsh.exe -noexit { ssh username@host }
  ```

  - However, note that it's rarely necessary to call the PowerShell CLI from inside PowerShell (which involves creating a *child process*). Here you could simply call `ssh username@host` *directly*.
- **From *outside* PowerShell**, use **`pwsh -Command " ... "`** (or `pwsh -c " ..."` ); in your case (as in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74223364/45375)):

  ```bash
  pwsh.exe -noexit "ssh username@host"
  ```

  - *Outside* can mean:

    - Calling from *another shell*, notably `cmd.exe`

      - Calling from another shell means that *its* syntax requirements must be satisfied first, which can get tricky with `"` chars. that are escaped as `\"` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375) for robust workarounds.
    - Calling from a *no-shell* context such as the Windows `Run` dialog (<kbd>WinKey+R</kbd>) and commands launched by Task Scheduler.
    - All (native) outside contexts on *Windows* require *double*-quoting (`"..."`), but if you're calling from a *Unix* (POSIX-compatible) shell such as Bash, *single*-quoting is also an option.

For a **comprehensive overview of the PowerShell CLI**, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68136128/45375).

---

**Background information**:

`{ ... }` is the literal form of a PowerShell [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), loosely speaking a reusable piece of code that must be *invoked on demand*, either with [`&`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) (in a child scope) or with [`.`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) (directly in the caller's scope):

- Only ***inside* PowerShell** can it be used with the PowerShell CLI to pass commands to execute, because PowerShell there offers **`{ ... }` as *syntactic sugar***:

  - Behind the scenes, the code inside the script block is Base64-encoded and passed on the command line that is ultimately constructed via `-EncodedCommand`; similarly, any arguments passed to `-Args` are Base64-encoded and passed via `-EncodedArguments`, and CLIXML (PowerShell's XML-based inter-process serialization format) is requested as the output format via `-OutputFormat XML`
  - This, in conjunction with *automatic deserialization* of the output received, ensures that the benefits of PowerShell's rich (.NET-based) type system and multiple output streams are preserves as much as possible (*type fidelity has inherent limitations when serialization is involved* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375)).
- When the PowerShell CLI is called **from the *outside*** (or even via *string* from inside PowerShell), the syntactic sugar does *not* apply, and **a script-block literal** (invariably provided via a *string* argument) **is parsed as *just that***: a piece of code to be *called later*.

  - Thus, if you try something like the following:

    ```bash
      # !! WRONG - simply *prints* what's between { and }
      # (Also applies if you don't use "..." from outside PowerShell.)
      pwsh -c "{ Get-Date }"
    ```

    - PowerShell constructs a script block, and, since it is not assigned to a variable, *outputs* it by default, which means a *string representation* of the (otherwise unused) script block prints, which is the *verbatim content* of the script block, sans `{` and `}`.
    - That is, verbatim  `Get-Date`  is printed, which you can also verify as follows from inside PowerShell: `{ Get-Date }.ToString()`

---

<sup>[1] *Technically*, you could use `"& { ... } ..."` if you wanted to pass *arguments* from *inside* your command string to the embedded script block, though that level of encapsulation will rarely be necessary in practice; a contrived example (call from outside PowerShell):

`pwsh -c "& { 'Time is now: ' + $args[0].TimeOfDay } (Get-Date)"`</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I used curly braces that apparently don't work in cmd, but do work in pwsh. To make the command work in CMD, just use double quotes: 
`pwsh.exe -noexit -Command "ssh username@host"`

Answer (score 0):

See the `-Command` parameter in the [pwsh documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh?view=powershell-7.2). cmd.exe doesn't know the *ScriptBlock* concept and interprets `{ssh test@test}` as a string.

When triggering pwsh.exe from cmd.exe, you should do something like this:

```
pwsh.exe -noexit -Command "& {ssh test@test}"
```

Comment: Thank you! I already figured it out (see answer below), but what is the "&" for here? Do we really need it here?

Comment: @MySurmise: No, there's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly, as you did in your own answer. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Comment: Also, `pwsh -Command` can be called with a script block as well (from inside PowerShell, where using a script block _implies_ `-Command`), so it isn't about whether `-Command` is used, it's about whether a true script block is passed (only possibly from inside PowerShell) or whether a _string_ representing a script block. When a _string_ is passed, a script block embedded in it _is_ parsed as such, but isn't _executed_. In other words: it is _not_ interpreted as a string; it does become a script block, but, in the absence of it being invoked or saved, is _output_, as its _verbatim content_.