# How to pass an If statement to the Argumentlist of Start-process for PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, powershell-5.1

```
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major,$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Minor -join "." -gt 5.1) {   
    
Start-Process -FilePath "PowerShell.exe" -ArgumentList 'if((get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SmbDirect).state -eq "disabled"){Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SmbDirect -norestart}'
}

else
{
if((get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SmbDirect).state -eq "disabled"){Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SmbDirect -norestart}
}
```

even though I made it a one-liner, It still won't work. the result is a new PowerShell window opening for a split second and closing.

how can I make it work?

I studied the [Argumentlist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3#-argumentlist) but couldn't find a way.

Comment: Why use start-process or call powershell again?

Comment: @js2010 because https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13866

Comment: This works for me:  `start-process powershell "if(1 -eq 1) {echo hi} ; pause"`

Comment: You can call powershell.exe without `Start-Process` then all output goes to your console.

Comment: `get-WindowsOptionalFeature` runs smoothly in my *PowerShell 7.3.1*. Update your `pwsh`…

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thank you so much, I didn't know I could do that, well that solved my problem and made it easier

Comment: @JosefZ I am using PowerShell 7.3.1 and when I type `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -online` it waits for like 20 seconds and then show `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature: Class not registered`. installed from Microsoft store app.

Comment: glad to hear it :) normally one would use `Start-Process` for async calls or in some cases it is required like with `msiexec` where the `-Wait` is needed. but most of the times it is as simple as calling the executable from the shell itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing the title of the question, this works ok for me.  "powershell -command" is implied.

```
start-process powershell "if(1 -eq 1) {echo hi} ; pause"

hi
Press Enter to continue...:
```

This looks like a "losing the doublequotes problem".  See also [PowerShell stripping double quotes from command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714165/powershell-stripping-double-quotes-from-command-line-arguments)

```
powershell '"a"'

a : The term 'a' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
```

Swap the single and doublequotes.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "PowerShell.exe" -ArgumentList "if((get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SmbDirect).state -eq 'disabled'){Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SmbDirect -norestart}"
```

Not that start-process is needed.

```
PowerShell.exe "if((get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SmbDirect).state -eq 'disabled'){Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SmbDirect -norestart}"
```

That Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature command works for me in powershell 7.2.8.

Comment: Sorry but i still see a new PowerShell window flash. I added `;pause` to it to see what happens and all I saw was "Press Enter to continue...:"

Comment: Works for me.  If state is enabled nothing will happen.

Comment: You're right, it was enabled and I was expecting for output saying it's enabled, forgetting it's an `if` statement.

Comment: Your solutions are effective, but note that the problem you link to is a separate issue, which is unrelated to the use of `Start-Process`

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

- To make your command work, **escaped the embedded `"` chars in your `-ArgumentList` argument as `\"`**.

  - Alternatively, use embedded `'` chars escaped as `''`, or use `"..."` for the outer quoting, in which case you can use `'` as-is - but note that this bears the risk of *up-front* expansion of variable references and expressions, unless you escape `$` instances as `` `$ ``.
- However, **`Start-Process` may not be the best way to invoke your command**; if *synchronous* invocation with *output to the caller's console* is desired / acceptable, use a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) to pass your command as-is (works from *inside* PowerShell only):

  ```
  PowerShell.exe { 
    if((get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SmbDirect).state -eq "disabled"){Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SmbDirect -norestart} 
  }
  ```

---

##### Background information:

[js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74915142/45375) provides effective solutions, but let me try to provide **a systematic overview of the issues involved**, to avoid potential misconceptions:

- **Calling [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI (or its [PowerShell (Core) equivalent, `pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh), *from PowerShell* is rarely necessary**.

  - You state that in your case you *did* need to do so, *from [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)*, because functionality wasn't available in the latter, due to a [potential bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13866).
- **As with any *external program*, you have *two basic invocation choices***:

  - *Direct* invocation (possibly via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), which is *situationally* required [for syntactic reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678081/45375)).

    - Direct invocation is *usually* the right approach, as it executes the program *synchronously*, with the program's output streams connected to PowerShell's, which by default displays them *in the caller's console*.
    - From *inside PowerShell*, irrespective of whether you're calling the respective *other* edition on Windows, using a script block (`{ ... }`) is the best choice - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74228152/45375).
  - Invocation via [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process), which by default executes *asynchronously*, in a *new window*, and is therefore only needed in *special circumstances*.

    - See [GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239) for guidance on when use of `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate.

---

The fundamental problem with your own approach is that **any `"` characters** in the `-ArgumentList` argument ***must be escaped as* `\"`**:

- **Passing a piece of PowerShell code to a PowerShell CLI's `-Command` (`-c`) parameter** (*by default* with `powershell.exe` only, *explicitly* with `pwsh`) employs ***two* parsing passes**:

  - In short: ***unescaped* `"` chars. are *stripped* during *command-line* parsing**, and only then are the argument(s) interpreted *as PowerShell code*.

    - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124361/45375) for details.
  - **Any `"` characters you want to be *part of the PowerShell code to evaluate*, must be *escaped***.

    - Using embedded `'...'` quoting, if possible, is a way to avoid this need.
    - PowerShell itself, in both editions, *always* recognizes `\"` as an escaped `"`, but when calling *from `cmd.exe`*, different forms are needed in *edge cases* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060341/45375).
- **When using `Start-Process`** with a *single-string* `-ArgumentList` argument:

  - **The (possibly preprocessed by PowerShell) string's *verbatim value* becomes part of the raw process command line** that is constructed behind the scenes, so using `\"` to escape `"` chars. is enough.
- **When using *direct invocation***:

  - **It is reasonable to *expect* PowerShell to *automatically* escape embedded `"` characters, such as when calling `powershell.exe '"hi"'`**

    - However, **due to a long-standing bug up to v7.2.x, this does *not* work as expected** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375).
  - In **PowerShell 7.3.0 and 7.3.1**, specifically, it ***does* work as expected *by default***, however, **a *future update* will likely require *opt-in*** - see [GitHub issue #18694](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18694)