# On WSL2 how do I get a powershell command's output to print to stdout

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In WSL2 I want to run a powershell command and get the output of the command to print to stdout on my WSL2.

I have tried many variants but it seems I always just get the command given back and not its output:

```bash
$ pwsh.exe -Command {Get-Date}
Get-Date

$ pwsh.exe -Command '{Write-Output "hello"}'
Write-Output "hello"
```

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/types-of-cmdlet-output?view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use curly braces here :

```
pwsh.exe -Command 'Get-Date'
```

Answer (score 1):

[Philippe's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75416489/45375) provides the crucial pointer:

When calling **[`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh)**, the **PowerShell (Core) CLI**, **from *outside* PowerShell**:

- **Do *not* use `{ ... }` to enclose your command(s)** - that only works from *inside* PowerShell.

  - Inside PowerShell, `{ ... }` creates a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) literal, which is a reusable piece of PowerShell code that can be invoked *on demand*.
  - If you **pass `{ ... }` to `pwsh` from *inside* PowerShell, *special processing* happens** behind the scenes, which notably preserves type fidelity in the output as much as possible - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74223450/45375) for details.
  - It should be noted that calling the PowerShell CLI *from PowerShell* is rarely necessary, except, for instance, on Windows, if you want to call the respective *other* PowerShell edition's CLI.
- **Instead, pass your command(s) as-is, inside a *string***.

  - If you pass a string to `-Command` from outside PowerShell *with `{ ... }` embedded*, what happens is that PowerShell *creates a script block* and - in the absence of *invoking* it, with `&`  or `.`  - its *string representation* is output, which is the block's *verbatim content* (excluding `{` and `}`) - that is what you saw.
  - As an aside: There are many examples out there that use `"& { ... }"` as a `-Command` argument; while that technically works, it is *unnecessary*, and passing just `"..."` (or `'...'`, from POSIX-compatible shells) is sufficient.

Thus:

```
# Simple case: no quoting necessary
$ pwsh.exe -Command Get-Date

# Command string that requires quoting:
$ pwsh.exe -Command 'Write-Output "hello"'
```